# Convert String to class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert a string into a specific class. The string is the class name. I have a sql procedure that returns three sets of data, the master record for the Client Class. Then the secondary, Address Class, and lastly another secondary class, Contact class.

I'm using SqlDataReader to return the sql procedure data and using the reader.nextResults() to go through the data.

The string value is coming from the SQL procedure.
Eg : "Address" or "List_Contact".

```
public static class Client
{
   Guid Id { get; set;}
   string ClientName { get; set;}
   Address ClientAddress { get; set;}
   List<Contact> ClientContacts { get; set;}
}

public static class Address
{
   Guid Id { get; set;}
   Guid ClientId { get; set;}
   string AddressLine1 { get; set;}
   string AddressLine2 { get; set;}
   string AddressLine3 { get; set;}
   string AddressLine4 { get; set;}
   string PostalCode { get; set;}
}

public static class Contact
{
   Guid Id { get; set;}
   Guid ClientId { get; set;}
   string ContactNumber { get; set;}
   string ContactType { get; set;}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you parsing a comma separated string and assigning properties? I'm having a hard time following this. More information would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If you have three different result sets why do you need the class name?  Can't you just process the result sets in a defined order?

Comment: Also you might want to use some sort of a ORM system, for example, Dapper: https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: And by the way - why is your classes are static (and properties -are not)?

Comment: @JleruOHeP there is no specific reason why the classes are static. They don't have to be. I will look into the Dapper example.

Comment: @DStanley, I'm trying to create static method that will be able to handle any set of classes that is passed to it and map them to there corresponding classes.

Comment: **@vikingben**, The data will be returned in columns and there will be one column that shows the name of the class and if it is a list.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Activator.CreateInstance("your assemble name", "your class name")` method. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d133hta4) is more infomation

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I would use reflection;

```
Dictionary<string, Type> dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
dict.Add("Foo", typeof(Foo));
dict.Add("Bar", typeof(Bar));

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(dict[className]);

...

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new foo");
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("new bar");
    }
}
```

**OLD**

I would use a `switch` statement.

Example:

```
object obj;
switch(className)
{
    case "Foo":
        obj = new Foo();
        break;
    case "bar":
        obj = new Bar();
        break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String manipulations get tricky after a while. plus it may not work in your case, since there would be no way of linking the actual 3 classes.

See if this approach makes sense:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Client> clients = new Dictionary<Guid, Client>();

// first read all the Client records.
while (reader.Read())
{
 Guid clientId = Guid.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString());
 Client tempClient = new Client();
 tempClient.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
 // construct the tempClient completely using all fields.

 clients.Add(clientId, tempClient);
}

// now move onto the address records.
reader.nextResults();

while (reader.Read())
{
 Guid clientId = Guid.Parse(reader["ClientId"].ToString());
 clients[clientId].Address = new Address();
 // construct the clients[clientId].Address completely using all fields.
}

// now move onto the contact records.
reader.nextResults();

while (reader.Read())
{
 Guid clientId = Guid.Parse(reader["ClientId"].ToString());
 Contact tempContact = new Contact();
 // construct the tempContact completely using all fields.

 clients[clientId].Contacts.Add(tempContact)
}

// at the end, the clients dictionary has all the Client objects linked with the right 
// Address and Contact objects.
```

1. your sql procedure needs to have 3 select statements: clients, addresses & contacts.
2. in the code we construct the clients first.
3. we then use the clientid field of addresses to link the address object to the right client.
4. we do the same for the contacts.